# Initialising smart pointer

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new)

Whats the difference between the following initialisations? In the tutorial, it is as in case #1 but does it make any difference if i use the #2 way below?

```
struct X
{
    X() {}
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    std::auto_ptr<X> p1(new X);   // #1
    std::auto_ptr<X> p2(new X()); // #2
}
```

Comment: See this good reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smart pointer doesn't make any difference here. Both smart pointers are initialized in the same way, with a pointer to `X`. The difference is how `X` is initialized. If there is a difference and what the difference is depends on how `X` is defined. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/620402/185171) answer has an excellent description of what happens in different cases. In this case since `X` has a default constructor they get initialized the same. However if there were no default constructor they would be initialized differently.